# Resultado do mysqli_fetch array diferente do que o executado no phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Eu tenho o seguinte código php que faz uma consulta ao banco de dados e retorna um vetor com os dados.

```
 public function executeSelect($query){

            $resultado_id = mysqli_query($this->objetoConexao, $query);

            if($resultado_id){

                //Passa para um vetor o resultado da query
                $dados_usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                return $dados_usuario;
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }

        }

$query = "SELECT *
              FROM prova_dados INNER JOIN prova_fotos ON (prova_fotos.id_dados_prova = prova_dados.id)
                GROUP BY prova_fotos.id_dados_prova ";

    $select = $dao->executeSelect($query);

    echo var_dump($select['materia']);
```

Porém quando eu executo essa query no phpmyadmin na "mão" ela me retorna duas linhas, com os dados agrupados como eu quero, mas no retorno do mysqli_fetch_array ele me mostra somente uma linha.

resultado da mesma query no phpmyadmin

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

echo var_dump do php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua consulta deve mesmo retorno só uma linha? se não precisa de um while e retornar um array.

Comment: Ela deveria retornar duas linhas, pois no meu banco tem 2  prova_fotos.id_dados_prova diferentes

Comment: não seria echo var_dump($dados_usuario[]); ?

Comment: De um `var_dump($select);` e veja a estrutura de retorno do resultado, talvez tenha que colocar em um foreach para imprimir os resultados

Comment: @MatheusLopesMarques Se fizer com os colchetes vazio da erro

Comment: que erro da? tenta sem os colchetes

Comment: Eu consegui resolver com o código da resposta de baixo, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repare que você identifica como `$dados_usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` conflitando o `mysqli_fetch_array` com o parâmetro indicado, que é `MYSQL_ASSOC`.

O correto seria desta forma abaixo

`mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

e também você não define uma variável para percorrer os dados / registros em array, repare na resposta

```
 public function executeSelect($query, $objetoConexao){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM prova_dados INNER JOIN prova_fotos ON (prova_dados.id = prova_fotos.id_dados_prova)
            GROUP BY prova_fotos.id_dados_prova ";

        $resultado_id = mysqli_query($this->objetoConexao, $query);

        $valores = array(); /* Você não tinha criado uma variável para definir array */

        if($resultado_id){

            //Passa para um vetor o resultado da query
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            $valores['Aqui coloque o name do input'] = $row['Aqui coloque o nome da tabela que deseja percorrer'];

        } else {

        return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($objetoConexao) ));        
    }

        return json_encode($valores);

}
```

Ou se não for o que você quer, tente desta forma, com While percorrendo os campos e retornando, mas aqui eles irão ser retornados no formato tabela pois eu delimitei que eles irão ser trazidos dentro de uma tag `<td>`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM prova_dados INNER JOIN prova_fotos ON (prova_dados.id = prova_fotos.id_dados_prova) GROUP BY prova_fotos.id_dados_prova";

$resultado_id = mysqli_query($this->objetoConexao, $query);       

$row = array(); /* Você não tinha criado uma variável para definir array */

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_id)){

   echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>". $row['Nome da tabela que quer percorrer'] ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row['Nome da tabela que quer percorrer'] ."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: Consegui com segundo código, muito obrigado, mas eu não entendi o porque funcionou dessa maneira, a diferença está no mysqli_fetch_assoc né?

Comment: Também faz diferença, afinal você declarou mysql_fetch_array e depois dentro do parâmetro identificou como MYSQL_ASSOC, conflita entende? E também repare no código acima, eu defini uma variável $row, como sendo um array, e percorro este array utilizando while, de uma forma com que ele percorra todos campos que você quiser, DESDE QUE ESTES CAMPOS EXISTAM DENTRO DAS TABELAS DO SELECT, entendeu ?

Answer (score 0):

O que faltou no seu caso foi um while.

Modifique a sua função para que fique assim:

```
public function executeSelect($query){

        $resultado_id = mysqli_query($this->objetoConexao, $query);

        if($resultado_id){

            //Passa para um vetor o resultado da query
            while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $response[] = $dados;
```

}

```
            return $response;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }

    }
```